# MS SQL Backup Database to FileStream

Tags: sql-server, database

I want to backup a database from a MS SQL Server Instance. If I save the backup to .bak file it works fine. But I want to save the backup as stream.

Is this possible?

Comment: not sure what you mean, can you clarify the question please?

Comment: Do you want to backup a FILESTREAM database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save a backup of a database to a filestream you will first need to create the file with a normal backup operation and then add the file to a filestream.  I do not believe there is a way to backup directly to a file stream, 'out of the box'.

If it was a FileTable that would be different.  You would just create the .bak file to the correct folder and would have access to the filestream as soon as the .bak file finished writing.